# scraping multiple differnet urls simultaneously using scrapy splash using python

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I need to scrape multiple url concurrently using scrapy and splash.. i tried writing following code, but still no luck.. 
I have attached the URLS.. here..
'https://wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/brooklyn/',
'https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/pa/california/', 
'https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/boston'

so I need to iterate through these URLs and then scrape it using scrapy.
I'm unable to get get the data using the multi url.. it's showing error. Please help
My question is how can I further scrape this list of URLs?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import scrapy_proxies

class WundergroundSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wunderground'
    #allowed_domains = ['www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/brooklyn']
    start_urls = []

    script = '''
    function main(splash, args)
        splash.private_mode_enabled = false
        assert(splash:go(args.url))
        assert(splash:wait(10))
        return splash:html()
    end
    '''
    
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
        'https://wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/brooklyn/',
        'https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/pa/california/',
        'https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/boston'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,  args={'wait': 8})

    def parse(self, response):
        tmps= {
            'tempHigh': response.xpath("//div[@class='forecast']/a[@class='navigate-to ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='obs-forecast']/span/span[@class='temp-hi']/text()")[0],
            'templow': response.xpath("//div[@class='forecast']/a[@class='navigate-to ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='obs-forecast']/span/span[@class='temp-lo']/text()")[0],
            'obsphs' : response.xpath("//div[@class='forecast']/a[@class='navigate-to ng-star-inserted']/div[@class='obs-forecast']/div[@class='obs-phrase']/text()")[0]
            }
        yield tmps
```

Comment: So what is the question ? Problem ?

Comment: Hey Alexandre, I tried above code, but still no luck..it's showing error.. I put splash script out of the code also.. no luck..

Comment: looks like a typo in your first url: `https:///wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/brooklyn` should probably be `https://www.wunderground.com/forecast/us/ny/brooklyn`

Comment: No Wim,It's not the problem.. I corrected it. Just wanted some alternate solution also..if that makes more sense.

Comment: Would be useful if you can describe the problem, and show what errors you're getting when you execute the code above

Answer (score 0):

you created your lua script but never used.

try this:
yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse,endpoint='execute', args={'lua_source':self.script})